# How do I read a video from Minoru 3d webcam in OpenCV Python?

Tags: java, python, c, opencv, video

I am working on opencv python installed on Windows 10 (64 bit)
I am using Minoru 3D webcam.I wrote a code on reading a video from 2 lens camera.I am here with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/pythoncode/reading a video from two lens", line 6, in <module>
    if(cap & cap1):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'cv2.VideoCapture' and 'cv2.VideoCapture'
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
if(cap & cap1):
    while(true):
        ret, frame=cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('bgr image',frame)
        print ret
        ret1, frame1=cap1.read()
        cv2.imshow('image1',frame1)
        print ret1
        if cv2.waitKey(30)>=0:
            break
        cap.release()
        cap1.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: DON'T SHOUT AT US PLEASE!

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'cv2.VideoCapture' and 'cv2.VideoCapture'

Answer (score 0):

Your code and error messages were incredibly hard to read; please put four spaces before every line of code, or select all of the code and press Ctrl+K, turning

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python27/pythoncode/reading a video from two lens", line 6, in if(cap & cap1): TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'cv2.VideoCapture' and 'cv2.VideoCapture' import numpy as np import cv2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1) if(cap & cap1): while(true): ret, frame=cap.read() cv2.imshow('bgr image',frame) print ret ret1, frame1=cap1.read() cv2.imshow('image1',frame1) print ret1 if cv2.waitKey(30)>=0: break cap.release() cap1.release() cv2.destroyAllWindows()

into

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/pythoncode/reading a video from two lens", line 6, in <module>
    if(cap & cap1):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'cv2.VideoCapture' and 'cv2.VideoCapture'

    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    if(cap & cap1):
        while(true):
            ret, frame=cap.read()
            cv2.imshow('bgr image',frame)
            print ret
            ret1, frame1=cap1.read()
            cv2.imshow('image1',frame1)
            print ret1
            if cv2.waitKey(30)>=0:
                break
        cap.release()
        cap1.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

According to the error message, the error is in the line `if(cap & cap1):` and it occurred because you cannot use the operator `&` (bitwise AND) on two `cv2.VideoCapture` objects.

I assume you are trying to make sure neither variable is `None`, and the way to do this is to change the line to:

```
if (cap != None) and (cap1 != None):
```